# Node and linked list syntax in C

Tags: c, database, pointers, linked-list, structure

I want to realize the above functions:

```
struct _book
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    char Author[20];
    int quantity;
    float Price;
    int rack_no;
};

typedef struct _book book;

typedef struct _node
{
    book* data;
    struct _node* next;
} Node;

Node* book_list=NULL;

void createPassword(void);
int logIn(void);
void sellBook(void);
void addBook(void);
void changePassword(void);
void searchBook(void);
void printZeroQuantity(void);
void printBooks(void);
void logOut(void);
void updateQuantity(void);
void entry(void);
void deleteBook(void);
void updateQuantity(void);
```

Hey I'm a new “programmer,” barely two months, I have a question about structures and linked list in C.

I want to build an application to manage a library DB.

In addition, I want to received implement functions that get as a parameter `void` And return `void` for example like this function: `addBook(void)`, which means that all the structures are global throughout the program.

My question is how I read the head of the linked list From the function Instead of sending the pointer to the top of the `link_structures` for example like this: `book make_book(book *booklist,int count)`.

Do you think it is advisable to build semi function that will create
`Node* new_node(int data)` Or its not necessary?

```
book *Addbook(book *book_list,int *counter)
{
    book Newbook;

    int size, num, size1, size2, flag, check, i, size3;

    char *tempfirst, *templast, *tempphone;

    int *temprackno, *tempid;

    double *tempprice;

    (*counter)++;

    book_list = (book*)realloc(book_list, (sizeof(book)*(*counter)));

    book_list[*counter-1] = Getbook(book_list, ((*counter-1)));

    printf("\nA book was added seccesfully");

    return(book_list);        
}

book Getbook(book *book_list, int count)
{
    book NewBook;
    int size, num, size1, size2, flag, check, i, size3, counte;

    char *tempfirst, *Author, *tempphone;

    int *temprackno = 0, *tempid = 0;

    double *tempprice;

    tempfirst = (char*)malloc(M*(sizeof(char)));

    Author = (char*)malloc(M*(sizeof(char)));

    tempphone = (char*)malloc(M*(sizeof(char)));

    while((tempfirst==NULL) ||(Author==NULL) || (!tempid) || (!tempprice) )
    {
        tempfirst = (char*)malloc(M*(sizeof(char)));
        Author = (char*)malloc(M*(sizeof(char)));
        tempid = (int*)malloc(M*(sizeof(int)));
        tempprice = (double*)malloc(M*(sizeof(double)));
    }
```

last question: what's wrong with this line? The program falls while running, and there is no value entered to the new node.

**scanf("%d", &(new_node->data->id));**

```
{

Node* new_node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
printf("\nPlease enter the book id:");
scanf("%d", &(new_node->data->id));
printf("\nPlease enter the book name:");
scanf("%s", &(new_node->data->Author));
printf("\nPlease enter the book quantity:");
scanf("%d", &(new_node->data->quantity));
printf("\nPlease enter the book rack:");
scanf("%d", &(new_node->data->rackno));
}
```

Comment: A little (and unrelated) not about your structure naming, structure names lives in their own name-space, so you can have a structure with the same name as a type alias. E.g. you can have `typedef struct book { ... } book;`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,using the same name as the struct leads to confusion for the reader of the code.  Strongly suggest using unique names

Comment: regarding calls to `realloc()`  1) in C, do not cast the returned value from `realloc()`, `calloc()`, `malloc()` as the returned value is type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) When calling `realloc()`, always assign the returned value to a temporary variable, then check (!=NULL) that temporary variable before assigning to the target variable.  Because if `realloc()` fails, which it can do, then the pointer to the original memory allocation is lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: when calling `scanf()` and family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  `scanf()` returns the number of successful input/conversions.  If the returned value does not match the number of format specifiers, then an error has occurred.

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s", &(new_node->data->Author));`  without a max characters modifier on the '%s' format specifier, the user can overrun the input buffer which is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Be sure the max characters modifier is 1 less than the actual length of the input buffer as the '%s' format specifier always gets a NUL char appended to the input.

Comment: this question is asking about a runtime problem, but the posted code code does not cleanly compile, infact it does not compile at all.  Please post a minimal, complete code that still shows the problem.  Post by adding text, not editing the existing text.

Comment: if `book_list` is global, then why is it being passed as a parameter to the two posted functions?  Note: the second function posted is missing some trailing code.

Comment: for readability and understandability by us humans, please follow the axiom:  only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: to change where a variable, that is passed in as a parameter to a function, is pointing, need to pass the address of the variable.  I.E. the original caller passes `&book_list`  and each function parameter list has `book **book_list`  Then each place that wants to change the pointer in book_list would have the lvalue written as: `*book_list =`

Comment: regarding this kind of line: ` book_list[*counter-1] = Getbook(book_list, ((*counter-1)));` the `-` has a higher precedence than the `*`, so the math will be performed before the dereference.  Suggest: ` book_list[(*counter)-1] = Getbook(book_list, (*counter)-1 );

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix the warning (and error) messages raised by the compiler.   (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (I also like to add: `-Wconversion -std=c99`) )

Comment: in C, using the name of an array (in almost all scenarios, including those in the posted code) degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  So the calls to `scanf()` when the parameter is an array name, must not have a `&` as the result is trying to take the address of an address which will not work

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  so using that expression as a multiplier in the parameter to `malloc()` has no effect, just clutters the code, and makes it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain the code

Answer (score 0):

You could keep it in a global variable and then use it in your function. Like:

```
...

typedef struct _node
{
    book* data;
    struct _node* next;
}Node;

struct Node *head;
struct Node *tail;

//more declarations

int main(void)
{  
    //code
}

...
```

Note: Name your variables with lower-case letters.

Initialize `head` and `tail` first, then use them directly in your functions.

About your second question, *why not*. But a better alternative would be `append` (similar to your new_node) and then `insert` function.

Note: You put above "`Node* new_node(int data)`" which will give you error, since the types are incompatible, better: `Node* new_node(book **data)`.

Hope it helps.